# How to maintain the elements order in JAXB generated XML from JaxbObjects

Tags: jaxb

I have run a sql query with order by clause with 2 column names to get the results in given order. Now I copy the values from resultset to jaxb objects and marshall it to xml.

My requirement is to get the xml in the same order as in resultset.

Eg: Select * from emp order by date,employeeid;

output

```
id          Date
4           22/01/2012
10          10/03/2012
```

Now I expect the xml as

```xml
<Employees>
  <Employee id="4" date="22/01/2012">
  <Employee id="10" date="10/03/2012">
</Employees>
```

Is there a way to get it done?

Regards
Harish

I have added new  integer variable "order" in jaxbObject. While reading the resultset and updating the jaxbobject, I update the order variable with counter. So from the xml generated from marshalling the jaxb objects, I can rely on the "order" to list in the same order as sql query returns.

Comment: I don't get it. Your SQL listed as you wanted(`order by`) and you just want those `Element`s listed as you got?

Answer (score 1):

**Order of `id` and `date` Attributes**

You can use the `propOrder` attribute on the `@XmlType` annotation to specify an order for fields/properties mapped to XML elements.  There isn't a way to specify the order in which XML attributes appear in the XML output (the order of attributes is not considered significant in XML).

**Order of `Employee` Elements**

The order in which `Employee` elements are marshalled out will depend upon the characteristics on the `Collection` used to store them in the Java model.

**For More Information**

- http://blog.bdoughan.com/2012/08/jaxbs-xmltransient-and-property-order.html